# 「か」 or 「と」 as a subordinate clause?

Tags: grammar, particle-と, particle-か, subordinate-clauses

When making a statement like:

> I thought I had gone to the cinema.

Do you say:

> 映画館{えいがかん}に行った{いった}と思いました{おもいました}。

or:

> 映画館{えいがかん}に行った{いった}か思いました{おもいました}。

And how does it work with other verbs that are not like thinking, considering, saying? Which one am I supposed to use then?

Comment: You type furigana inside `{ }` after the word and it gets automatically converted to ruby. Click on edit to see how it works. You type it in the same way regardless if you are using a browser or the mobile app.

Comment: What is the meaning you want to convey? I'm not sure in what situation you'd use the English phrase.

Comment: (Why am I here?) w w w w ............ [I thought I had gone to the cinema.] <-- Is this a case of amnesia? Confusing dreaming and reality? _______________________________This is clearly wrong: 映画館​に​行​ったか​思​いました。

Comment: `... as a relative clause... I thought I had gone to the cinema. 映画館に行ったと思いました` ← Is there a "relative clause"/関係詞節 in these sentences? The "that" in "I thought that I had..." is not a relative pronoun, is it?

Comment: @chocolate yes, there is a relative clause in there- "I had gone to the cinema." the "that" is used as a conjunction between the main clause and complement.

Comment: @user11589 Heh... My English grammar book (ロイヤル英文法) says that the "that" in "I know **that** he is here" "I think **that** he will accept the job" is a 名詞節を導く**従位接続詞** /subordinate conjunction, not 関係代名詞/relative pronoun. You can't rephrase the OP's sentence as "I thought **which** I had gone to the cinema", right?

Comment: @chocolate yes, you are correct! "I thought which i had gone to the cinema" is ungrammatical. Your book also seems correct.

Comment: Right, there are no relative clauses here in any of the English or Japanese examples.

Comment: @chocolate thx for furigana

Comment: Oh, it was not me. @macraf added the furigana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To say "think that (some sentence here)", 思う always takes the quotative particle, と. So 映画館に行ったか思いました is ungrammatical.

The following two sentences are grammatical:

> - 映画館に行ったと思いました。
>     I thought (someone) went to the cinema.
> - 映画館に行ったかと思いました。
>     I thought (someone) perhaps went to the cinema. / I wondered if (someone) went to the cinema.

The か in the latter sentence is a question marker, which in this case introduces some uncertainty to the sentence.